# Intersect 2 different kinds of collections based on string property of different name

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of 2 different kinds of objects.

I'm trying to do an .Intersect based on a string property......

```
public class EmployeeDto
{
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
}


public class PersonDto
{
    public string SocialSecurityNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Attempts:

```
            ICollection<EmployeeDto> empsColl = new List<EmployeeDto>();
            empsColl.Add(new EmployeeDto() { SSN = "222-22-2222", HireDate = DateTime.Now });
            empsColl.Add(new EmployeeDto() { SSN = "333-33-3333", HireDate = DateTime.Now });
            empsColl.Add(new EmployeeDto() { SSN = "444-44-4444", HireDate = DateTime.Now });
            empsColl.Add(new EmployeeDto() { SSN = "555-55-5555", HireDate = DateTime.Now });


            ICollection<PersonDto> pers = new List<PersonDto>();

            pers.Add(new PersonDto() { SocialSecurityNumber = "333-33-3333", Name = "John" });
            pers.Add(new PersonDto() { SocialSecurityNumber = "444-44-4444", Name = "Mary" });



            ICollection<EmployeeDto> overlap1 = empsColl.Where(api => api.SSN.Any(val => val.Equals(pers.Any(cl => cl.SocialSecurityNumber.Equals(val))))).ToList();

 ICollection<EmployeeDto> overlap2 = empsColl.Where(api => api.SSN.Equals(pers.Any(per => per.SocialSecurityNumber.Equals(api.SSN, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))).ToList();



            foreach (EmployeeDto emp in overlap1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(emp.SSN);
            }
```

The desired result is a `ICollection<EmployeeDto>` that contains the EmployeeDto objects of 333-33-3333 and 444-44-4444 of course.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how it can be done:

```
var overlap = empsColl.Where(e => pets.Any(p => p.SocialSecurityNumber == e.SSN)).ToList();
```

Comment: ICollection<EmployeeDto> overlap4 = empsColl.Where(e => pers.Any(p => p.SocialSecurityNumber.Equals( e.SSN, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))).ToList();

Answer (score 1):

I think this would do it

```
    empsColl.Where(ec => pers.Select(p => p.SocialSecurityNumber).Contains(ec.SSN)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
    var result =  empsColl.Where(x => pers.Any(y=> string.Compare(y.SocialSecurityNumber, x.SSN) == 0));
```